# How to apply a color to <td> tag in .ejs file in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I want to know how to apply a color in .ejs file. Here is the code.

```js
    <% resultList.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= item.function %></td>
    <td><%= item.value %></td>
    <td><%= item.content %></td>
   </tr>
  <% }); %>
```

if(item.value == false) //I want to apply red color

How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
<% resultList.forEach(function(item, index){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= item.function %></td>
        <% if (item.value === false) { %>
        <td style='color:red;'><%= item.value %></td>
        <% else %>
        <td><%= item.value %></td>
        <% } %>
        <td><%= item.content %></td>
    </tr>
<% }); %>
```

Note personally I think this is ugly. I would try to keep more code out of template side and would also use a CSS class for the coloring, but it was easier to illustrate this way.

Comment: Yes, This is what I want! Thank you!